# Switching from Linux Mint 13 to Ubuntu 12.04 - Saving Programs

Tags: system-installation, mint

I am still fairly new to Linux, and I was planning on switching from Linux Mint 13 (which I'm currently using) to Ubuntu 12.04. I have quite a few programs that I installed on Linux Mint outside of the software center - like StataSE 12 - and I was wondering, if I install Ubuntu 12.04, will these programs be deleted? Is there a way to indicate that I want to keep these programs during the Ubuntu install?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

> if I install Ubuntu 12.04, will these programs be deleted?

Yes.

> Is there a way to indicate that I want to keep these programs during the Ubuntu install?

No ...

But you can sort of prepare yourself before deleting Mint. In Ubuntu (probably the same in Mint) you can create a package list of installed software with ...

```
dpkg --get-selections > /tmp/installed.txt
```

save "/tmp/installed.txt" to a USB stick, after installing Ubuntu put installed.txt in /tmp/ and you can install the packages that are not yet installed with the normal setup with these 2 commands ...

```
dpkg --set-selections < /tmp/installed.txt
dselect
```

Unless you installed packages that are not in the official repositories this should work. Those missing packages you probably need to re-install manually.